# Find times value has been used and multiply it by amount across tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm doing a school assignment that has to do with gifts and their production time. We have the table "gift" which contains the name, gift_number and gift_production_time, and the table "wishes", which contains gift_number, wish_number and person_number. With these tables we have to calculate the amount of time it takes for all the gifts to be made in minutes and days rounded up.

Seeing as this is an introductory course to databases, I've hit a roadblock on this task. The closest I can get is to have a row for each gift, showing the production time of each of them individually, but not the total amount of time it takes.

Here is my closest attempt:

```
SELECT w.gift_number, count(w.gift_number)*production_time as total_minutes
FROM wishes as w, gifts as g
WHERE g.gift_number = w.gift_number
GROUP BY w.gift_number
```

I don't think I can get the correct answer with the GROUP BY statement, but the math isn't correct if I omit it. Any help would be much appreciated. :-)

**EDIT**

*Gift table*

```
|gift_number | gift_name | production_time
|_________________________________________
|1              gift1        130
|2              gift2        140
|3              gift3        200
|4              gift4        100
```

*Wishes table*

```
|wish_number | person_number | gift_number |
|___________________________________________
|1                  1              2
|2                  1              4
|3                  2              2
|4                  3              1
```

Comment: Don't they teach ANSI JOIN syntax in your class?

Comment: I don't think you need the wishes table at all.  Also, I think the sum function will be useful.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to calculate. Could you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I'm also thinking this should involve `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`.

Comment: Read this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp and this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp you should be able to figure the rest by yourself

Comment: @Drecker Please read this: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @fancyPants thanks though I see nothing wrong with that two specific pages a referred to (they're even tutorial-like pages not simply documentation, in this case I see it as good thing). Further more I wasn't able to find simple SQL information about SQL commands on any page w3fools referred to.

Comment: @Drecker Please use official platform documentation. w3schools is a **terrible** resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you are learning SQL, you should learn proper `join` syntax.  As a simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

Second, the query that you have written is incorrect from the perspective of SQL.  MySQL accepts it, but the problem is `production_time`.  It is not in an aggregation function (such as `sum()` or `min()`) and it is not in the `group by` clause.  So, you are using a MySQL extension.  And, you should only use this extension when you really, really understand what you are doing.

I suspect that the query you want is more like this:

```
SELECT sum(production_time) as total_minutes
FROM wishes w JOIN
     gifts g
     ON g.gift_number = w.gift_number;
```

Depending on how time is represented (an integer number of minutes?  as a time?  etc.) and how you want to see the results, you may need to use date/time functions.  I would suggest you review them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and play with them to get the results you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon, that's exactly what I was looking for! Our teacher hasn't specified any of those things you mentioned about SQL, but then again, we've only had this course for about 2 months.

Comment: Another trick your teacher probably wont mention: in MySQL, when joining tables, if the columns to be joined have the same names in both tables, you can use `USING` instead of `ON`. With your example, you could use `USING(gift_number)` instead of `ON g.gift_number = w.gift_number`